# libsndfile library build error in VS 2012 Vc++ app project

Tags: libsndfile

I am creating Visual Studio VC++ app project on Win 7, that utilizes the libsndfile library.

The library( libsndfile-1.dll,libsndfile-1.dll) is at :

> C:\SVN\US\AdditionalIncludeDir\libsndfile

and its headers(sndfile.hh,sndfile.h) at

> C:\SVN\US\AdditionalIncludeDir\Include

the Visual Studio Project is at :

> C:\SVN\US\Simulation\audioSim.vcxproj

I have added the library header reference as:

> Project properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories->
>   **..\AdditionalIncludeDir\Include**
>   and static lib reference as
>
> Project properties->Linker>Additional dependencies: 
>   libsndfile-1.lib
>   Project properties->Linker>Additional Library
>   Dir:**..\AdditionalIncludeDir\libsndfile**

I also have added

> ..\AdditionalIncludeDir\libsndfile

to  *path* in user environment variable in Win 7.

The toplevel C++ file uses the library as:

```
SndfileHandle mic1(".\\filedata\\mic1.wav");
```

where mic1.wav is at

> C:\SVN\US\Simulation\filedata

Building the project still gives me error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sf_open referenced in
 function "public: __thiscall SndfileHandle::SndfileHandle(char const
 *,int,int,int,int)" (??0SndfileHandle@@QAE@PBDHHHH@Z)
```

Why would this happen?

Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem. I had set "Additional Include Directories" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\include) and "Additional Library Directories" (C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\lib) in the project settings.

**This fixed the problem:**
Go to project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> Input and type in the lib file name **libsndfile-1.lib** in the **"Additional Dependencies" field**.